# xamarin formsでカメラ表示サンプルのフリーズの原因と修正方法が知りたい。

Tags: c#, xamarin, camera

Xamarin Formsのカメラ表示サンプルで質問します。

下記のサンプルを実行してみていますが、カメラビューをタッチするとカメラビューがフリーズしてしまいます。
おそらくキャプチャーされた画像が下に表示されるようなプログラムなのだと思いますが、サンプルソフトの
動きがわからなく、どこを修正すればいいのかがわかりません。
どこを修正すればいいのでしょうか？
https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample

Comment: 直接は関係無さそうですが、こんな修正 [Visual Studio 2019 v16.7 の Xamarin Android がデバッグの開始時にクラッシュする。](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.7.2) があったようなので、アップデートしてみると何か改善されるかも。

Comment: ありがとうございます。残念ながらVisual Studi 2019、パッケージ等をアップデートしてみましたが、現象改善はされませんでした。